# while looping, Images are not adding to UIImageView

Tags: swift, ios8, uiimageview

I am trying to scrolling image automatically in swift. I have tried below. I am trying to scroll through swift coding, instead of StoryBoard. It is scrolling well. But, Images are not adding to the image view. But, UIImageView bgcolour has been changed to green. My coding is below.

Kindly Guide me.

```
    var str_1 : String = "one.jpg"
    var str_2 : String = "two.jpg"

    let img_1 : UIImage = UIImage(named: str_1)!
    let img_2 : UIImage = UIImage(named: str_2)!

    img_arr.addObject(img_1)
    img_arr.addObject(img_2)

    scroll_view = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, 320, 130))

    for(var y : Int = 0; y < img_arr.count; y++)
    {


        //scr_img_vw = UIImageView(image: img_1)
        //scr_img_vw.addSubview(UIImageView(image: img_arr.objectAtIndex(y) as UIImage))
        scr_img_vw = UIImageView(image: img_arr.objectAtIndex(y) as UIImage)
        //scr_img_vw.image = UIImage(named: img_arr.objectAtIndex(y) as NSString)
        scr_img_vw = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(320 * CGFloat(y), 0, 320, 130))
        scr_img_vw.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        self.scroll_view.addSubview(scr_img_vw)


    }
        self.view.addSubview(scroll_view)
        scroll_view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll_view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(img_arr.count), 130)
        scroll_view.scrollEnabled = true
        scroll_view.pagingEnabled = true
        scroll_view.bounces = true
```

Comment: How do you declare your img_arr? Does it trow any errors?

Comment: var img_arr = NSMutableArray()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating image twice. Change the fore loop as follows:

```
for(var y : Int = 0; y < img_arr.count; y++)
{
    scr_img_vw = UIImageView(image: img_arr.objectAtIndex(y) as UIImage)
    scr_img_vw.frame = CGRectMake(320 * CGFloat(y), 0, 320, 130))
    scr_img_vw.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    self.scroll_view.addSubview(scr_img_vw)
}
```

The better swift way would be like this:

```
let img1 = UIImage(named: "one.jpg")!
let img2 = UIImage(named: "two.jpg")!

var imageArray = [UIImage]()
imageArray.append(img1)
imageArray.append(img2)

for (index, image) in enumerate(imageArray) {
    var imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(320 * CGFloat(index), 0, 320, 130))
    self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Comment: I have added a better way of doing what you are doing. This is more in spirit of Swift.

Comment: I got another too...!! @ abdullah